# Hide/Unhide StatusBar, TabBar and NavigationBar on touch

Tags: hide, statusbar

How to hide/unhide the status bar, tab bar and navigation bar on touch using TapGesture.
Can anyone give me the code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a tap gesture to the view

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideUIComponents:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Then the function hideUIComponents

```
- (void)hideUIComponents:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGesture
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
   [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

   CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
   [animation setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
   [[self.view.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"layerAnimation"];
   [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
}
```

Unhide by reversing the values. I hope this helps.

Comment: CATransition is an undeclared identifier for my project, why?
And what do you mean by reversing the values?

Comment: @JoakimJojoElgsæther Include the QuartzCore.framework to your project and #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> for CATransition. By reverse I mean change the setHidden values to NO :)

Comment: @JoakimJojoElgsæther All this is in the .m file

Comment: Ok, so I don't need to make any IBAction or anything? How do I connect this to the tapRecognizer?

Comment: @JoakimJojoElgsæther No.. [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer] takes care of that

Comment: So should I put i beneath viewDidLoad or just a random place?

Comment: Thanks! I think I figured it out now! ;)

Comment: Or actually... Could you wrote the code for reversing together with the rest of the code?

Answer (score -1):

You want to do it on tap gesture
Then use

```
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ViewTapped:)]
```

on the view that where you want to implement.

check whether status bar is hidden or not using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden];
```

and then
To hide status bar use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

and to show it again use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me the .h code and the .m code for it? I'm a really newbie so...